# jQuery: Clocklike show()

Tags: jquery, animation, geometry, jquery-animate, show

I've got this jsfiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9kw1oe46/4/)

It is just about a blue `<div>` circle *children* of another white `<div>` circle with border.

I want to *animate()* the red circle to show up on *doc.ready*, just like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.inner').show();
});
```

BUT what I want is this animation to show the circle in a circular way, like a radial `show()`, like a clock movement.

Let me explain this with an image:
[Example img](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-g5m4_0BaTP4/US4PwTD6NLI/AAAAAAAAGTo/7bqMnQ5kUqg/s1600/grafico-circular-css-2.jpg) This would be how it looks just after starting the animation.

I did not succeed on finding a plugin for that, and I have no idea where to start from programming this 
(so any idea or any plugin you know are both good answers).

Comment: This css tricks post might be along the lines of what you're looking for, but it'll probably require some tweaking: https://css-tricks.com/css-pie-timer/

Comment: That was absolutely what I was looking for. Thank you.